# How to implement archives in blog with ruby and sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, archive

I'm doing archives for my blog ,actually I'm moving from rails to sinatra because of the requirements.I'm trying the same for Sinatra

In my app.rb:

```
def index
   @posts = Post.all(:select => "title, id, created_at", :order => "created_at DESC")
   @post_months = @posts.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month }
end
```

and in Layout.erb :

```
<div class="archives">
   <h2>Blog Archive</h2>

   <% @post_months.sort.reverse.each do |month, posts| %>
   <h3><%=h month.strftime("%B %Y") %></h3>
   <ul>
      <% for post in posts %>
      <li><%=h link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
  <% end %>
```

Can anyone please help me how to do it for sinatra? I'm trying the same code and I'm getting this :undefined method `sort' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Sinatra's notation for defining actions. Instead of:

```
def index
  # your code...
end
```

You need to define actions like so:

```
get '/' do
  # your code...
end
```

You should probably read this before continuing: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html